# How to style menu local tasks

Tags: 7, theming

**Problem**

I'm trying to theme the menu local tasks that Drupal places without any unique css classes. How would I do this?

(Specifically I'm looking to hide certain links on certain pages by giving each one a unique css class).

*Links Sample HTML*

[image]

*Which is generated by this line in page.tpl.php.*

```
<?php if ($primary_local_tasks): ?><ul class='links'><?php print render($primary_local_tasks) ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
```

**So Far**

To do that I'm trying to use theme_menu_local_tasks however I can't get it to work. I've put this snippet in my template file but it doesn't print anything or show me any variables.

```
function tefltheme_menu_local_tasks (&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
  print("hello");
  return theme_menu_local_tasks($variables);
}
```

I'm using Tao sub-theme which means it splits menu local tasks into primary and secondary.

```
function tao_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Split primary and secondary local tasks
  $vars['primary_local_tasks'] = menu_primary_local_tasks();
  $vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = menu_secondary_local_tasks();
```

Could this be affecting anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`theme_menu_local_tasks()` will never be invoked using those two methods, so it makes sense that your `dpm()` fails.

Both functions do eventually invoke [`hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7), though, and that's where you can make your changes:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  if ($some_condition) {
    // Grab the first tab.
    $first_tab = &$data['tabs'][0]['output'][0];

    // Add a class to the link element.
    $first_tab['#link']['localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'some-class';
  }
}
```

If you want to add a class to the `<li>` element you'll need to go a step further, and override [`theme_menu_local_task()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_local_task/7).

The class attribute is hard-coded at the moment so that'll will need to be changed, based on a contextual variable you can pass into the theme function from the local tasks hook above.

That would look something like this in the alter hook

```
$first_tab['#extra_class'] = 'some-class';
```

And along these lines for the theme function

```
function MYTHEME_menu_local_task($vars) {
  // Copy the code from theme_menu_local_task() but change the HTML output
  // to include an extra class if $vars['extra_class'] is set
}
```

You might also need to implement [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) to let it know about the new variable (can't remember if it matters but it can't hurt)

```
function MYTHEME_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['menu_local_task']['variables']['extra_class'] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You've done it again Clive. That's worked perfectly. I ended up not needing to touch `MYTHEME_theme_registry_alter`.

Comment: Why did my original call not wipe out the theming for menu local tasks completely and cause them to vanish?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final code that went into my template file:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {

  //check the path of the page
  if ($root_path == 'user/register') {
        //add classes to the tabs. I left out tab 0 which is the active tab
        //and styled differently. It comes with active as a class.
        $tab1 = &$data['tabs'][0]['output'][1];
        $tab1['#link']['localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'tab1';
        $tab2 = &$data['tabs'][0]['output'][2];
        $tab2['#link']['localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'tab2';
  }
}
```